# Its posible to do this with the preg_match function?

Tags: php

Its posible to do this?

`!preg_match("/{1,31}/", $day)`

If its not between 1 and 31 do something.

Comment: You're probably looking for [checkdate()](http://php.net/checkdate).

Comment: No, that's a quantifier, not a number range. Use character classes and alternatives. See http://regexp.info/ for some intros.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is waaay overkill for this. Why not just use something like

```
if($day<1 || $day>31){
    //do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply constrain the value to limits use a combination of `max()` and `min()`:

```
<?php
$value = min(max($val, 1), 31);
?>
```

Or if you need to present an error on invalid input use:

```
<?php
if ($value > 31) {
// do something
} elseif ($value < 1) {
// do something different
} else {
// all is well
}
?>
```

Regex is certainly not needed.